# How can I embed an Angular app into a Wordpress page?

Tags: angular, wordpress

I created a finished Angular 7 app that is compiled and working (it is a small game). I want to include it into a page of my Wordpress installation.

1. Where do I put my compile output of the Angular app (the content of the dist folder after running ng build)?
2. How does the HTML code in my Wordpress page (HTML that embeds the Angular app) look like?

Comment: Use a `iFrame`.

Comment: https://laternastudio.com/blog/including-an-angular-7-app-inside-wordpress-laravel-or-any-php-page/

Comment: Thanks @Ollie. That page is no longer available in its original address but is now archived here: 
https://web.archive.org/web/20210603072953/https://laternastudio.com/blog/including-an-angular-7-app-inside-wordpress-laravel-or-any-php-page/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I made my solution working with iFrame:

In angular.json I configure for "prod"

```
"outputHashing": "none"
```

Then I build my Angular 7 app using the "prod" configuration:

```
ng build --prod
```

I copy the build output (usually $PROJECT_DIR/dist) into a sub directory "angular-app" inside the "wp-content" directory of my wordpress page.

Now the index.html of the Angular app needs a modification. Change

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<base href="/wp-content/angular-app/">
```

Notice that the trailing / in the base href path is absolutely necessary. It will not work without it.

On the target page of my wordpress installation I insert this custom HTML code:

```
<iframe id="angularFrame" title="My Angular App" frameBorder="0"
    src="http://wordpress-url.com/wp-content/angular-app/index.html" 
    width="600" height="600">
</iframe>
```

This displays my angular app on a wordpress page.

Comment: Why do you need to set `"outputHashing": "none"`? index.html will have the hashed names of the scripts anyway

Comment: src="http://wordpress-url.com/wp-content/angular-app/index.html" says that page not found

Comment: "wordpress-url.com" is just an example and you need to replace it with your actual wordpress URL

Comment: You can also deploy the Angular app to a separate app running on a sub domain and open that in an iframe. The main benefit would be better deployability. 

The Wordpress site is usually the main website of the company, while the Angular app serves a specific use case. Being dependent on deploying the whole Wordpress site for changes in the Angular app and vice versa is not great.

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you!!

Comment: There is no need to set "outputHashing": "none", it will work anyway, as @Ollie mentioned index.html will have all proper file names.